# using library highcharts with asp.net mvc 3

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, highcharts

I want to use the library highcharts with asp.net mvc 3 but the examples that I have found in the web is with asp.net mvc 2. The other thing is, how can I pass the result data from a linq query to a highcharts´s serie in my application.

And anyone that can provide an example of highcharts with asp.net mvc 3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A good way to do this is to configure your chart object using static Javascript and then load your chart series as JSON data using Ajax and the `addSeries` method. You can use the `Controller.Json` method to return your LINQ results as JSON. Assuming you are passing a numeric array to the `Controller.Json` method in your AJAX action, the following is a simple example of the JavaScript needed to do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
      chart: {
         renderTo: "<chart-div>"
      },
      title: { text: "Test Chart" },
   });
   $.ajax({
      url: "<query-url>",
      success: function(result) {
         chart.addSeries({
            data: result,
         });
      }
   });
});
```

Replace `<chart-div>` with your container and `<query-url>` with your Ajax URL or a call to `UrlHelper.Action`.

Answer (score 5):

Another way to do this is by using [DotNet.Highcharts](http://dotnethighcharts.codeplex.com/) library. You can build the Highchart entirely on the server side and there are a lot of [MVC3 samples](http://dotnethighcharts.codeplex.com/releases/view/80650).